# Htaccess - remove /page/ and add "-"

Tags: .htaccess

This is my third question about htaccess. I should've made one single. But I thought this would be too big of a question.

This is used for my own CMS. :o)

My htaccess is:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^page/([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L]

Remove index.php
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /.*index\.php\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.php$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

And what I would like to do is:

Remove /page/ from my URL, and just have for example: myurl.com/home

Right now my urls are: www.myurl.com/page/home or whatever title is given. Now, when people create new pages in the CMS, they maybe wan't a page called: About us.
And what this will en up being is:

www.myurl.com/page/about%20us

How do I add "-" instead of %20?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easy remove `page/` from the .htaccess, but you have to ignore existing files and directories:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

Your second problem has nothing to do with .htaccess. You have to link the page `About us` as `/about-us/` instead of `/about%20us/` (`%20` represents a space), and if the page `/about-us/` (`index.php?page=about-us`) is called just handle it as `/about%20us/`. So simply replace spaces with `-`.

Comment: Hmm, looks like 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L] 

Doesn't do anything at all? 

And my links are based on what people choose for their page title to be.. For example in my CMS, if they like the title to be About us. I wan't to handle About us to be about-us instead.

Comment: Now /page/ is removed from the URL, thanks for that one. <br>
Now: How do I get the %20 to be - instead?